# Как сделать отдельные рубрики и метки для каждого автора в одном и том же блоге на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Не могу найти плагинов, которые позволяют в одном блоге на Wordpress сделать отдельные рубрики и метки для каждого автора. По сути должен получится сайт где каждый автор может вести свой блог со своей структурой рубрик и своими метками.

Может я усложняю, а решение более простое и не нуждается в плагинах?

PS: Есть еще идея: у каждого автора своя одна рубрика, в которую они добавляют свои подрубрики. Но получается что URL страницы автора должен совпадать с URL его рубрики.

Comment: Авторов много? Все свои или кто попало, "с улицы"? И точно ли нужны "свои" рубрики/метки, почему нельзя им быть общими?

Comment: Много, с улицы. У каждого автора своя профессия, как хочет так и пишет.

Comment: Есть еще идея: у каждого автора своя одна рубрика, в которую они добавляют свои подрубрики

Comment: Тогда разворачивай мультисайт. И не забудь обзавестись армией юристов.

Comment: А зачем юристы?

Comment: Потому что люди "с улицы" напишут такого, что ты можешь сесть и надолго.